# Meaning of 코딱지만하다

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

I'm was watching a drama and came across '코딱지만하다'. I've found out that this means 'tiny' but what is the origin of this word? From what I know, 코딱지 = booger and 만하다 = to be worthy of, but how would these two words form the meaning of 'tiny'?

Thanks

Comment: The correct one is 코딱지만 하다 not 코딱지만하다, and you should read [this (No. 4)](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=86554) to understand the meaning of such a phrase or sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

코딱지, used figuratively, can mean something very tiny or worthless. It wouldn't be that hard to think of where this expression came from; booger really is small, and worthless.

As @Klmo said above, it should be 코딱지만 하다. The auxiliary verb 만하다 does exist, but it can only be used with other verbs, as in 이 정도면 할 만하다. Since 코딱지 is a noun, we see that 만하다 cannot be use here, which leaves us only one option: 코딱지만 하다. So you shouldn't interpret this phrase as "worthy of booger". "As tiny as a piece of booger" would be a better translation. Koreans will understand what you mean either way you spell it, but just being technical.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes perfect sense.